# Is the word Proxy a reserved word (J4)

Tags: joomla-4

This may be a silly question but I couldn't find anything stating that "proxy" was a reserved word.  I am working on my component for elections and wanted to register a user nominating another user to be his/her proxy for voting.
So when I had my singular view of "proxy" and my multiples view of "proxys" (yes spelled incorrectly deliberately) I have trouble returning from the edit view to the multi view in the admin side because the view name was always changed to "proxies".
Did my head in.

Comment: Hunted hi and lo where this was setting the view name to this "nefarious" change of name without success.  Resolved by changing the whole section of the component to "proxyvoter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J4 uses inflector library to pluralize list view names based on form view name. J3 also does something similar, but it's much more limited. One solution would be to use correct plural name for your view. Another solution is to declare `$view_list` property in your form controller:

```
class ProxyController extends FormController
{
    protected $view_list = 'proxys';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, never stop learning do I?  Cheers.